# For Loop that includes multiple values using "i"

Tags: r

I am trying to write an if loop that takes a barcode number once scanned, and adds the value 0.5 to a column in the data set. I have a sample of a hardcoded version of this if loop (value 1 meaning that barcode '4041' is the first barcode value in the data frame):

```
df <- read.csv('Data.csv')
tool <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a Barcode: "))
if (tool == 4041){
df$TIMES.USED[1] <- df$TIMES.USED[1] + 0.5 
} else {
print('Please Scan Again')
}
```

My data frame looks as follows:

```
  Barcode.Number    Type.Equipment Manufacture Times.Used
            4041        Flashlight    Surefire          0
            4680           Capstan       Honda          0
            4682 Deep Cut Band Saw   Milwaukee          0
```

I am trying to run a for loop that will take any barcode number, and once entered, add 0.5 into the Times.Used Column. I have played around trying to use value 'i', but I just cant quite figure it out. Value 'i' representing the varying barcode numbers taken as input in relation to the rows i which the times used column will be updated.

As far as expected output, I just want an input statement, and an output that just changes the value in the data set, nothing needs to be directly output into the console.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Are you missing parts of your code? Where is *i* used? Where is *tool* assigned?

Comment: I think you meant "for loop" or "if statement". There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Comment: I dont have i used yet in my code, the rest of my code is mostly just blocks that need to be put together correctly, but I went back and put it back into my question. Thank you.

Comment: What is special about tool 4041? Do you only want to update the `TIMES.USED` column if the user happens to enter 4041?

Comment: Hi Gregor, I have the number 4041 as a sample representing my first barcode in the data table. There are almost a thousand numbers in the data frame, but I just used 4041 as the example for this question. Rather than writing something that changes the values of TIMES.USED in the 4041 row, Im trying to figure out how to write something that changes TIMES.USED in any row depending on the code entered.

Comment: Please add expected output to your post.

Comment: @zx8754 I went back and added that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
tool <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a Barcode: "))
# check if tool is in the the data
if (! tool %in% df$Barcode.Number) {
  # if not, tell user
  message("Barcode not found.")
} else {
  # if so, update data
  df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, "Times.Used"] = df[df$Barcode.Number == tool, "Times.Used"] + 0.5
}
```

When I run this code and enter '4041' at the prompt, this is the result of printing `df`

```
> df
  Barcode.Number    Type.Equipment Manufacture Times.Used
1           4041        Flashlight    Surefire        0.5
2           4680           Capstan       Honda        0.0
3           4682 Deep_Cut_Band_Saw   Milwaukee        0.0
```

---

Using this input data:

```
df = read.table(text = "Barcode.Number    Type.Equipment Manufacture Times.Used
            4041        Flashlight    Surefire          0
            4680           Capstan       Honda          0
            4682 Deep_Cut_Band_Saw   Milwaukee          0", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This runs really well. I appreciate the help!