# Adding a date to a frame based on input

Tags: r

I have an input variable for a data set in R that assesses a list of tools. It looks as follows:

```
type <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a Barcode: "))
```

I have two columns, one that contains the information found with the input statement (a set of barcode numbers), and one that contains a date that a certain thing was entered into the 'tool' variable. I understand how to use function Sys.Date and it works fine for me, I am just having a hard time getting it to update the column in the data frame when something is scanned rather than outputting the current date in the console. Ideal output for this would be just an update to the data frame column, in the row that the barcode scanned is. For example:

```
Barcode_Number, Date_Used
5698, 2018-07-07
4570, 2018-07-11
```

Thank you.

Comment: If this is an infrequent thing, just create a single-row frame (`data.frame(Barcode_Number=type, Date_Used=Sys.date())`) and `rbind` with the original data.frame.

Comment: @r2evans. Thank you for the reply but Im not exactly looking for something infrequent, more something that can update based on the date something is entered using Sys.date, and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have hoped you could generalize from [the last question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51271580/903061) - this is really similar. Let's work it through:

```
# load sample data
dd = read.table(text = "Barcode_Number, Date_Used
5698, 2018-07-07
4570, 2018-07-11", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

# make sure the date columns is Date class
dd$Date_Used = as.Date(dd$Date_Used)

# get barcode to update
barcode_update <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a Barcode: "))

# make the update
dd[dd$Barcode_Number == barcode_update, "Date_Used"] = Sys.Date()
```

---

Now let's compare to your last question, where you wanted to update the column named `"Times.Used"`. We'll pretend we're using the same variable name, `barcode_update` to hold the user input:

```
dd[dd$Barcode_Number == barcode_update, "Date_Used"]  = Sys.Date()
dd[dd$Barcode_Number == barcode_update, "Times.Used"] = df[df$Barcode_Number == tool, "Times.Used"] + 0.5
```

The left hand sides of the assignment are identical, of the form,

```
dd[dd$Barcode_Number == barcode_update, "Name of column to update"] = ...<new values>...
```

Data frame are referenced with brackets using `data_name[rows, columns]`. In both of these cases, we want to update certain rows: the rows where the barcode number matches the user input. So we do that test: `dd[dd$Barcode_Number == barcode_update, ]`. You could update the 3rd row with `dd[3, ]`, the 1st, 2nd, and 5th rows with `dd[c(1, 2, 5), ]`, or use some really complicated condition, maybe all the barcodes that have 0 in them `dd[grepl("0", dd$Barcode_Number), ]`.

In the *column* argument of `[`, we just need the name of the column to update, in quotes. Nice and simple. You could even use a variable there, that has the column name stored in it.

The right hand side gets the new value. This question is simple - you want the new value to be the date returned by `Sys.Date`, so we do `= Sys.Date()` (or `<- Sys.Date()`, whichever you prefer). In the previous question, you wanted to add 0.5 to the existing "Times_Used" column, so we put the exact same thing on the right as on the left, but with a `+ 0.5` tacked on.